# How do you ensure compatibility JavaScript libraries for the browser and for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, compatibility

I'm working with a team on a [TypeScript librabry called Classical.js](https://github.com/drubino/Classical), and we would very much like the core module of this library to be JavaScript environment agnostic. In my mind, that means it should not only function correctly cross-browser, but also as a dependency in a node.js project.

First of all, am I missing any major JavaScript environments in my test matrix that I should be aware of?

Unfortunately no one on the team develops with node. Therefore we're not quite sure what APIs to avoid (*obviously the DOM*) to ensure compatibility. Are there are a standard set of GOTCHAs that node developers run into when using code that has only been tested in the browser?

One discrepancy that we did (hopefully) account for the name of the global scope, which, if memory serves me correctly, is represented by an object named *global* in node and *window* in the browser. These are the sort of GOTCHAs that we are looking for.

Comment: If you develop first for node and then want to port to the browser, you might look into [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: Most server+client-side developers that I am aware of actually go the other way around - they develop for node, pretty much exclusively and then shim the browser with node APIs that they need on the client side.  That said, this is a bit broad for a question - better to hash some things out in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and deal with more specific questions here.

Comment: I'm tring to develop for neither, but we do run jasmine in the browser. Ideally, we are only using language constructs.

Comment: Well, in a sense, I'm getting my answer - this is a bigger issue than just a few functions to avoid, and objects that are renamed. But isn't that worth explaining, rather than down-voting? I would certainly mark a cogent argument on why this is a complex topic as correct.

Comment: I'm bummed about the down-vote. I'd really appreciate an experienced node developer explaining the magnitude of the difference between the two JavaScript environments. A downvote makes that much less likely

Comment: @DougR As others have said, I'd definitely recommend going the other way around and using Browserify to compile your JavaScript.  I actually use it for most of my projects, even if I'm only targeting code to run within the browser, as it allows me to use `require()` without strange side effects.  I pipe the output of Browserify through UglifyJS to bring the size down a bit as well.

Comment: @Brad I think Doug's question is not about *how* to create such a library but rather what to take into account for creating an isomorphic library. If your node.js library is heavily relying on `fs`, it's not going to work in the browser you know. Same for browser libraries relying on the DOM: not usable in node.js.

Comment: Thank you @Brad. We are designing TypeScript tools intended intended to enable framework construction. They have no dependence on the browser. My team has a .Net background and are not a part of the node.js community. But TypeScript is used on both sides of the fence, so we thought it would be most prudent to create an isomorphic library. I'm not going to apologize for learning JavaScript in the context of the browser, nor for using C# as my backend language of choice. I was trying to be open-minded and accomodating to a community other than my own. It's an odd thing to be criticized for.

Comment: @DougR I didn't criticize you at all... was only offering advice and an example of my own workflow.  I apologize if your read of my commend came off as criticism.  I also didn't down-vote you.  (I actually up-voted you, and your comment about the no-comment downvote.)

Comment: This was a misunderstanding and I apologize for my tone. I thought we were debating why I should have been down-voted.

Comment: Brad: It occurs to me that from the commit numbers, Classical looks like a new project. Classical is developed in TFS, a source control system with better Visual Studio support. Last week I wrote a build script wich pushes to GitHub. There are actually many thousands of commits (and man hours) in this library, so you might imagine we are disinclined to port to a new and unfamiliar dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an important issue here, one that that's currently underexposed: you want to create an isomorphic library, and you want to know which libraries you depend on are isomorphic. I think it would be a good thing when isomorphic modules would be clearly marked as such in for example npm.

There is a nice blog on this topic here: http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

Basically, isomorphic libraries should only use functionality build in JavaScript the language itself (ES3, ES5, ES6, ...).

- You should avoid anything related to the DOM (window, document, navigator, ...), as this is only available inside a browser environment.
- Many core modules of node.js cannot be used in a browser (like file system, os, process, network, streams, etc). For many core modules there are browser safe versions available (for example for crypto and http). Browserify uses these versions when bundling a node.js app for use in the browser.
- There are a lot of JavaScript engines out in the wild, implemented in all kind of languages like C, Java, Python, etc. Also running directly on hardware like Espruino. These engines may not be 100% compliant with the language specs. For example, I encountered one day that the JS engine in Java (I think it was Rhino) didn't like a variable to have the name `boolean`. In these cases I would argue that these engines should get better compliancy rather than you having to work around their bugs/limitations.

Anyway, there is an easy way to test whether your library is isomorphic: try to run it in both node.js and the 5 biggest browsers :)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer